# Android database cursor lifetime

Tags: android, exception, sqlite, cursor, listactivity

I have been trying to understand and solve this problem for the last three days.
I have multiple ListActivities where each one queries the same database. In every activity I close and reopen DB connection in onPause() and onResume() respectively. I populate list adapters with cursors which I also close and reopen:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    if(currentCursor != null){
        currentCursor.close();
        currentCursor = null;
    }

    if(mDbHelper != null){
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDbHelper = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mDbHelper == null){
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
    }

    if(currentCursor == null){
        new LoadNewListTask().execute();
    }
}


private class LoadNewListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            currentCursor = mDbHelper.fetchNewRows();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String arg){
        if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(currentCursor != null && currentCursor.getCount()>0){
            String[] from = new String[]{DbHelper.KEY_ID, sortingColumn};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.ai_about_author_btn, R.id.ai_author_name};

            MyAlphabetizedAdapter notes = new MyAlphabetizedAdapter(this, R.layout.author_index_item, currentCursor, from, to, sortingColumn);
            setListAdapter(notes);
        }
    }
}
```

On the first glance it works good however when I move fast between activities I sometimes get annoying Cursor Exceptions one saying this:

```
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a
close SQLiteClosable
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:31)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:56)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1118)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1092)
05-01 14:45:05.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at
apt.tutorial.Restaurant.getAll(Restaurant.java:14)
```

and another one saying this (this happens a LOT on 2.1 devices):

```
09-03 11:30:19.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2541): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
09-03 11:30:19.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2541): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@45b99828 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
09-03 11:30:19.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2541):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
09-03 11:30:19.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

What is more one of my ListActivities implements AlphabetIndexer where I have to pass the cursor. Very strange thing happens after I leave the activity and come back using back button. The list is populated (as expected) however when I try to use fast scrolling I get a null exception on the cursor even thought I recreated it and repopulated the list onResume().

For me it looks like OS cannot handle multiple cursors properly or maybe I miss something here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I've had issues with Activities that try to keep multiple cursors alive.  Especially when trying to use a managed cursor which I now try to avoid if possible (plus they're deprecated).  Now, what I try to do is open the cursor, populate an array of objects with the data I need, close the cursor and then use an ArrayAdapter to populate the ListView.   If you DO need to keep the cursor alive, and you should only need to if other activities on your stack are changing data, use a cursor manager or, better yet, the newer CursorLoader.  When doing this, don't close the cursor, as your activity will manage the lifecycle of the cursor for you.

Comment: I am using ArrayAdpters with custom objects in my other project and everything works fine. Using cursor requires less resources however I dint know that it will so frustrating to manage them all.

Comment: Yup - I've been there (as evident but one of my still unanswered questions).  I had an activity that I was trying to manage 3 or 4 cursors at the same time.  What finally worked was using the ArrayAdapter approach with all but 1 cursor that I need to keep alive (the data would change).

Comment: I don't think using arrays instead of a cursor is a good idea from the memory point of view

Answer (score 2):

Since you start an async task and you leave the activity fast, means that when the task return you will have leave from this activity, thus `onPause()` has been called and cursor is not closed. You could try to cancel the async task in the `onPause()`.

Comment: You have a good point however I wait for the AsyncTask f finish and then I move to next activity.

Comment: Hmm, have you checked if fetchNewRows() returns null then?

Comment: yes I did and it returns data. Everything works as expected when I don't close cursor onPause() but we should aren't we? Is the SimpleCursorAdapter take care of the cursor's lifetime?

Comment: Nop, the adapter just uses the cursor you provide him based on the activity lifecycle. The handling of the cursor lifecycle should be mamaged by the activity.

Comment: but how can I make the activity to start managing cursor? Previously I used startManagingCursor() however this method is depreciated.

Comment: No I am not, how can I call managedQuery() on provate database, I thought it's only for content providers